# while updating a new version app is updating to the newer version but need to manually clear data

Tags: android, android-manifest

Say "My android application is running on my server properly. now I want to update my application. while  I'm updating my application older version taking the newer version but need to clear the data from settings manually. As I can't tell so  many users to do that, so how can I solve this problem programmatically?"

like in manifest I add   below receiver code

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
   <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.CLEAR_APP_CACHE"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions"/>



<receiver android:name="">
         <intent-filter android:priority="100">
<action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_INSTALL"/>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED"/>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED"/>
<data android:scheme="package"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Then I added the clearing data code .

I expect that while app is installing to the newer version the data will be cleared and the application will run smoothly.

But it is  clearing data showing me the toast, still I need to clear data manually for entering the application.

Comment: Are you sending API version and app version to in APIs?

Answer (score 1):

In manifest you have something like this

```
    <application
        android:name=".VarzybosLazybosApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

change `android:allowBackup="true"` to `android:allowBackup="false"`

Comment: No, it is not working. Actually my problem is when i release an update my  current version will go to the newer version ,so during that time it install the application but without clearing the data app  is preventing  me from entering the  application.

Comment: I dont think that it is good practice to have any data data that is preventing update to newer version. Is it some SQLite storage problem after database update? If it is you should version your database and handle database updates when updating app